# Is onResume of activity guaranteed to be called?

Tags: android, android-activity, oncreate, onresume, start-activity

If I open Activity B in onCreate of Activity A, is it guaranteed for onResume() of Activity A to be called? For all OS versions? Is there any case where Activity B will open and Activity A stops and onResume of Activity A is never called at all.

Comment: I'd assume this is undefined and OS level specific, and may even depend on timing.  The definition of when onStart and onResume are called has to do with the Activity appearing on screen.  Since it may never do so, its possible they aren't.  Its also possible they are, depending on how Google coded it.  I wouldn't rely on this behavior either way.

Answer (score -1):

`onResume()` will be called whenever the activity becomes available and ready for user input.

But if you call `finish()` immediately in `onCreate()`, then `onResume()` will **NOT** be called.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        startActivity(Intent(this, ActivityB::class.java))
        finish()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume")
    }
}
```

Comment: not calling finish(). But starting another activity

Comment: @Nishita I've edited my code snippet. If you call `finish()` immediately after `startActivity()`, even then `onResume()` will not be called. But if you navigate to another activity after some delay, then `onResume()` gets called.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with finish()

Comment: @Nishita What I'm saying is that `onResume()` will be always called after `onCreate()` when navigating to another activity unless there is some closing interruption like calling `finish()`, which in your case there's nothing as such.